# Display vocabularies/terms inside content-type view

Tags: 7, views

I'm working with D7 and Views 3.  I created a view for my term pages (type=content, to show all my tagged content, which is a products' catalog). So far so good.

But now I would like to display in the same term page the vocabulary to which the selected term corresponds, along with all its siblings-terms, and a list of all the other vocabularies (without their terms), so the user can click on them and change the product category they're viewing.

I have my catalog like this:

Vocabulary A
 - Product A1
 - Product A2
 - Product A3

Vocabulary B
 - Product B1
 - Product B2
 - Product B3

Vocabulary C
 - Product C1
 - Product C2
 - Product C3

And I'm trying to have this in my view (supposing I'm viewing product C2):
 Vocabulary A
 Vocabulary B
 Vocabulary C
 - Product C1
 - Product C2 (selected)
 - Product C3
 Plus the other fields that belong to my product content type.

The idea is that the user can easily move between categories, and have the current category they're viewing with all its terms displayed.

Can I accomplish this with a single view? I tried adding taxonomy:name, term:name, etc as fields to my current view but I just managed to display the current term name and that's it. Can I create a taxonomy view inside my content view? or maybe this can be accomplished with arguments and relationships?

This is my first Drupal site so I'd appreciate any suggestion to know if I'm on the right track.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new view block within your View definition and define it using contextual filters to display the appropriate content.  Then go to admin/structure/blocks and move the block to the regions you wish it to appear in.  One of the options for configuring the block will be to assign what pages it shows up on.  By entering taxonomy/terms/% or whatever other path alias you are using you can limit where these additional blocks will appear.